# Add to the existing url in html's href

Tags: html, url

I am at a simple web address, lets say http://www.example.com/domain/nextdomain, and when I click a button, I would like to add a url parameter to that domain so that it becomes http://www.example.com/domain/nextdomain/new

It has to be dynamic because the base urls can change e.g. domain/nextdomain might become secondDomain/nextdomaintwo

**HTML**

```
<a href="new"><button></button></a>
```

I've tried the following, but it goes back a level to http://www.example.com/domain/new

```
<a href="new/"><button></button></a>
```

Comment: You can do it from server-side or with JS/Jquery, but with just plain HTML, I highly doubt it is possible at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `/` appended to the end your `href` (`"new/"`) you need to include HTML's `<base>` element to set the base url up in the `<head>` tags of your document -

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/domain/nextdomain">
```

The obvious issue here being that you need a fixed URL for your `base` tag. A way around that might be to populate it using some server side scripting.

Another option would be to use Javascript in order to populate the base tag client side - but at that point I would just say make a script to populate an `href` for your link. You would also be able to do that with some server side scripting.

To have something dynamic like the way you want it I do not believe it is possible using pure HTML.

To read up more on the usage of base tags - http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.4